# Why is my button ignoring the CSS for my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a menu that is off screen and appears if I click a certain button. The jQuery code works, but my button is below the menu instead of next to it.

I've tried wrapping all the elements in a div with a maximum height of 100% viewport height, but that's not working.

Is there anything I a doing wrong? HTML, CSS and jQuery provided in the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/u9bq5v2g/

The button is not visible at first glance because you have to scroll down first to be able to see it.

HTML:
    
        
            
                Home
                Profile
                Profile

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="menubutton">Menu</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menubutton").click(function(){
            $("#list").css("margin-left", "0vw");
        });
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

#list {
    margin-left: -15vw;
    max-width: 15vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(40, 35, 35);
}

.nav-pills>li>a {
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-pills>li>a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(66, 57, 57);
}
```

Comment: you haven't any css for your button? nav and button are block elements so they will display beneath each other

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs But shouldn't the wrapper with that maximum height force the button to be placed on the right side of the menu?

Comment: No, because the `nav` is `display: block` and the `button` is `display: inline-block`.

Comment: as @RoryMcCrossan said - by default it's `display: block`, place your `button` inside the `nav` tags in a container `div` and put a `display: inline-block` on the `div` would be best (probs best to put the links in a container `div` too with `display: inline-block`)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Thank you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is a better approach, this is taken from a tutorial. Make use of it if you find it useful. Its a similar logic, except it uses absolute positioning.

```js
$("#open").click(function(){
  $("#mySidenav").css("width","250px");
  $("#main").css("margin-left","250px");
});

$(".closebtn").click(function(){
  $("#mySidenav").css("width","0");
  $("#main").css("margin-left","0");
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

.closebtn{cursor:pointer;}
#open{
font-size:15px;
background-color: #ff0000;
padding: 10px 5px;
cursor:pointer;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a class="closebtn">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span id="open">MENU</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an amazing solution, looks fancy as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use float left to list and btn.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#menubutton").click(function(){
       $("#list").css("margin-left", "0vw");
      });
     });
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
 min-height: 100vh;
 max-height: 100vh;
}

#list {
 margin-left: -15vw;
 max-width: 15vw;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-color: rgb(40, 35, 35);
  float:left;
}

.nav-pills>li>a {
 border-radius: 0px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-pills>li>a:hover {
 background-color: rgb(66, 57, 57);
}
.btn{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    
 <div id="wrapper">

     <nav id="list">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="menubutton">Menu</button>

 </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: But now the button is above the menu, though. I'm looking for a way to get it to the side of it, to eventually make a "slide in" menu.

Comment: Incorrect - as @JonathanvandeGroep said that will just put it above the nav -1 (if I had the rep)

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you.

here is new solution 
Use float left to list and btn. 
https://jsfiddle.net/u9bq5v2g/4/

Comment: @ShifutHossain Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want your button to the left of the menu, you'll need

```
nav {
  display:inline-block; 
}
```

as nav is a block element. Move your button before the list

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="menubutton">Menu</button>
<nav id="list">
```

and move list further left to makeup for the width of the

```
#list {
        margin-left: -30vw;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/auqhysr1/

After seeing your comment about sliding in the menu I've updated my jsfiddle to do just that in CSS, although its on hover not on click and is reliant on CSS3.